# Update my component data from localstorage with reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I have a store application and its catalog component stores data on localstorage. But I need that from the data inserted in the localstorage another component has its state changed.

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

import './style.css';

function Footer(props) {
  const colorThemeFooter = props.colorThemeFooter;

  const [cont, setCont] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {

    const cont = localStorage.getItem("cartCont");
    setCont(cont);

}, [cont]);


  return (
    <div className="footer-default" style={{background: colorThemeFooter}}>
        <div className="footer-container">

          <p>{cont}<a href="https://github.com/kewineic">&copy;Kewin</a> - <a href="https://b2w.gupy.io/">Desafio Loja Pokemon</a></p>

        </div>    
    </div>
  )
}

export default Footer;
```

Is there a way to do this without redux or mobx?

Comment: You can check `useReducer` https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer

Comment: Thanks, I will check out the doc and some tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- yes you can use `context` API to store your global state easily specially with `useContext` hook like this:

```
    import {createContext, useState} from 'react;
    export const Store = createContext(null);
    export default function Provider({children}){
        const storedCont = JSON.parse(localStorage.get("cart-cont")) || []
        const [cont, setCont] = useState(storedCont);
        return <Store.Provide value={{cont, setCont}}>
        {children}
        </Store.Provider>
    }
```

- in other file you can use it easily like this:

```
import {useContext} from 'react';
import {Store} from './store.jsx'
const otherComponent = () => {
    const {cont, setCont} = useContext();
    // update cont with setCont
}
export default otherComponent;
```

- don't forget to make the Provider component the parent of your whole app

Comment: Thank you, your solution helped me

Comment: I am happy to help